# When using RestClient's ExecuteAsync<T>() method, what do I need to do for IRestResponse<T>.Data to populate correctly?

Tags: c#, serialization, httprequest, restsharp

I have the following code:

```
            _restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri(_personioConfig.BaseUrl, "/v1/auth");
            _restClient.Timeout = -1;
            _restClient.AddHandler("application/json", () => new JsonDeserializer());

            IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
                .AddQueryParameter("client_id", _personioConfig.ClientId)
                .AddQueryParameter("client_secret", _personioConfig.ClientSecret)
                .AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.OnBeforeDeserialization = response =>
                response.ContentType = "application/json";

            IRestResponse<AuthorizationRequestResponse> requestResponse = await _restClient.ExecuteAsync<AuthorizationRequestResponse>(request);
```

where `AuthorizationRequestResponse` looks like:

```
public class AuthorizationRequestResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "success")]
    public bool WasSuccessful { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public Token Token { get; set; }
}
```

When I execute this and the request is successful, I *expect* `requestResponse.Data.WasSuccessful` to be `true` and `requestResponse.Data.Token` to be have content that corresponds to the serialized value in `requestResponse.Content`.

Or, in other words, I would expect

```
                AuthorizationRequestResponse? authorizationResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthorizationRequestResponse>(requestResponse.Content);
                Assert.Equal(authorizationResponse, requestResponse.Data);
```

However, in *actuality*, `requestResponse.Data.WasSuccessful` is always `false` and `requestResponse.Data.Token` is always `null`, regardless of `requestResponse.Content`'s value, which in Visual Studio's debugger, I can see (for example) looks like:

`"{success\":true,\"data\":{\"token\":\"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhGciOi\"}}"`

(Token value truncated for conciseness and security.)

Am I missing or misunderstanding something?
What more do I need to do for ``requestResponse.Data` to be populated as expected, or am I entirely wrong to expect this?  In which case, why does it exist?

Comment: What does the actual response from the service look like?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, if there is a way to export the ENTIRE response from Visual Studio's debugger, I don't know it, but I added an abbreviated sample value of Content above.  If there are other values in the response which you may find important or interesting, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `JsonProperty` attribute, but do you use `NewtonsoftJson` as a deserializer? I don't think so. Assuming that `JsonDeserializer` is the one provided by RestSharp, you are using SimpleJson.

If you want to use `Newtonsoft.Json`, there's a package for it ( `RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson`).

The issue here is definitely deserialization if you get the 200 success code.

For the request/response inspection, the easiest way today is to use `HttpTracer` and provide a wrapped handler to RestSharp as [described](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#delegating-handlers).